# Concatenation of 4 input fields

Tags: jquery, concatenation

I am very new to the JavaScript world but I am trying to grab the input value from 4 separate input fields and concatenate them into a string so that I end up with a time, that i can use with moments timezone to output the in various different destinations around the world. Initially I am just trying to concatenate the 4 input's into one but when tested with alert, display `NaN`. Any guidance would be great.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var time1 = $("#time--1").val();
  var time2 = $("#time--2").val();
  var time3 = $("#time--3").val();
  var time4 = $("#time--4").val();



  $('.btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var time = time1.val + time2.val + time3.val + time4.val;

    alert(time);


  });

});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) which retrieves the value of the field as a String or Number, and then you're calling `val` on that, which would return `undefined`. `undefined + undefined == NaN`.

Just sum your variables: `var time = time1 + time2 + time3 + time4;`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your reply, I have changed the above but got the same result as i was definign my variable on page load, meaning it was still outputting NaN because it was taking the value of the inputs when the page loaded. Now I have moved the variable inside the click function, output is correct:

$(document).ready(function() {

$('.btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

```
var time1 = $("#time--1").val();
var time2 = $("#time--2").val();
var time3 = $("#time--3").val();
var time4 = $("#time--4").val();


var time = time1 + time2 + time3 + time4;

alert(time);
```

});

});